# Why can't I pass a custom field variable to 'numberposts' variable in Wordpress array?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm going crazy here - I can't figure out why this doesn't work!

I have a wordpress template with multiple queries to show different post types.

I am able to do this no problem:

```
 $showfeatposts = "1";
$args = array(
'numberposts'     => $showfeatposts,
'orderby'         => 'post_date',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'cat'             => '58',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);
```

Which passses the value of "1" into the 'numberposts' variable.

What I NEED to do is instead replace that value of "1" with a value passed from a custom field in the admin panel so that the administrator can enter the number of posts they want to show.

When I change my code instead to this:

```
$showarticleposts =  the_field('articles-posts-to-show');
$args = array(
'numberposts'     => $showarticleposts,
'orderby'         => "post_date",
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'cat'             => '5, -58',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);
```

I get all posts returned, as if the value being entered is '-1'

I've verified that the actual value in the custom field is '2' by enchoing it on the page.

What am I doing wrong? Surely this should be possible?

For reference: [Here's the page](http://2080baseball.com/homepage-testing/).

ETA: I've also tried this method from an ACF tutorial - still doesn't work:

```
$args = array(
'numberposts'     => get_field('showarticleposts'),
'orderby'         => "post_date",
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'cat'             => '5, -58',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true
```

ETA2: In response to the answer below - I have also tried this option:

```
$showarticleposts =  get_field('showarticleposts');

$args = array(
'numberposts'     => $showarticleposts,
'orderby'         => "post_date",
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'cat'             => '5, -58',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);
```

And if I put this code on the page - it does echo the number '2':

```
<?php echo get_field('showarticleposts'); ?>
```

Per request - here is the full page of code - I have tried to clean it up as much as possible - you will undoubtably notice the weird coding for the reports section, I am taking this over from someone who used Types to create the custom fields and custom post types. But I am using ACF custom fields for my attempt to add the ability to choose how many of each post-type to show on the homepage:

```
section id="content" role="main" class="clearfix animated">

    <?php
    /**
     * If Featured Image is uploaded set it as a background
     * and change page title color to white
    **/
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $page_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'big-size' );
        $page_bg_image = 'style="background-image:url(' . $page_image_url[0] . ');"';
        $title_with_bg = 'title-with-bg';
    } else {
        $title_with_bg = 'wrapper title-with-sep';
    } ?>

   <!--<header class="entry-header page-header">
     <div class="page-title <?php echo isset( $title_with_bg ) ? $title_with_bg : ''; ?>" <?php echo isset( $page_bg_image ) ? $page_bg_image : ''; ?>>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </header>-->

    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grids">
            <div class="grid-8 column-1">
        <?php
        // Enable/Disable sidebar based on the field selection
        if ( ! get_field( 'page_sidebar' ) || get_field( 'page_sidebar' ) == 'page_sidebar_on' ):
        ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php 
            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="page-content">
           <?php the_content(); ?>
           </div>

 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

 <?php  $showfeatposts = "1";
$args = array(
'numberposts'     => $showfeatposts,
'orderby'         => 'post_date',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'cat'             => '58',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$featposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $featposts as $post ) :  //setup_postdata($ppost); 
setup_postdata( $post );  ?>

    <div class="col-md-12 recent feat" id="recent">
     <figure class="entry-image inview">
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
       <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'rectangle-size-large' ); ?></a>
     <?php } ?>
 </figure>
        <header class="entry-header">
         <div class="entry-category">
          <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> / <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> </div>  
             <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
             <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
            </h2>
        </header>
 <div class="entry-content">
  <?php echo apply_filters("the_content", $post->the_excerpt) ; ?>
</div>
<div class="entry-category">
<span class="posted-on">By 
<span class="author vcard"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
$pnum++;
endforeach; ?>
    </article>

   <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
     <div class="col-md-12 homehdr">
     <header class="section-header">
    <div class="title-with-sep">
    <h2 class="title">Recent Articles</h2>
    </div>
   </header>
   </div>

  <?php $showarticleposts = "4";

$args = array(
'numberposts'     => $showarticleposts,
'orderby'         => "post_date",
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'cat'             => '5, -58',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$artposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $artposts as $post ) :  //setup_postdata($ppost); 
 setup_postdata( $post );  ?>                   

         <div class="col-md-6 recent arts" id="arts">
           <figure class="entry-image inview">
              <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'rectangle-size' ); ?>
                    </a>
            <?php } ?></figure>
          <header class="entry-header">
         <div class="entry-category">
         <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> / <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></div>  
        <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
         </h2>
   </header>
   <div class="entry-content">
 <?php if ($post->post_excerpt) the_excerpt();  else { ?>
 <?php $content = apply_filters("the_content", $post->post_content);
 $content = strip_tags($content); 
 echo substr($content, 0, 100); }
  ?></div>
<div class="entry-category">
<span class="posted-on">By 
<span class="author vcard"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
$pnum++;
endforeach; ?>
</article>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <div class="col-md-12 homehdr">
     <header class="section-header">
    <div class="title-with-sep">
    <h2 class="title">Recent Videos</h2>
    </div>
        </header>
        </div>
      <?php    $showvideoposts = "2";

$args = array(
'numberposts'     => $showvideoposts,
'orderby'         => 'post_date',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'cat'             => '3, -58',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$vidposts = get_posts( $args );


foreach( $vidposts as $post ) :  //setup_postdata($ppost); 
 setup_postdata( $post );  ?>

                   <div class="col-md-6 recent vids">
    <?php $video_embed = wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'add_video_url', true ) ); echo '<figure class="video-wrapper">' .$video_embed. '</figure>';  ?>

       <header class="entry-header">
        <div class="entry-category">
          <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> / <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> </div>  
         <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
          <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
       </h2>
  </header>
  <div class="entry-content">

<?php echo $post->the_content; ?>
</div>
    <div class="entry-category">
<span class="posted-on">By 
<span class="author vcard"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
$pnum++;
endforeach; ?>
                </article>


 <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <div class="col-md-12 homehdr">
  <header class="section-header">
    <div class="title-with-sep">
        <h2 class="title">Recent Notes</h2>
    </div>
        </header>
        </div>
                <?php
                $shownoteposts = "2";
$args = array(
'numberposts'     => $shownoteposts,
'orderby'         => 'post_date',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'post',
'cat'             => '42',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$noteposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $noteposts as $post ) :  //setup_postdata($ppost); 
 setup_postdata( $post );  ?>

        <div class="col-md-6 recent notes">

        <header class="entry-header">
      <div class="entry-category">
      <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> / <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>

</div>  
     <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
  <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
     </h2>
     </header>
     <div class="entry-content">

<?php echo apply_filters("the_excerpt", $post->the_excerpt) ; ?>
</div>
    <div class="entry-category">
<span class="posted-on">By 
<span class="author vcard"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></span>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
$pnum++;
endforeach; ?>
                </article>


<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
               <div class="col-md-12 homehdr">
                <header class="section-header">
      <div class="title-with-sep">
        <h2 class="title">Recent Reports</h2>
    </div>
        </header>
        </div>
                <?php
                $showreports =  get_field('showreports');

$args = array(
'numberposts'     => $showreports,
'orderby'         => 'post_date',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'post_type'       => 'reports',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$reptposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $reptposts as $post ) :  //setup_postdata($ppost); 
 setup_postdata( $post );  ?>

  <div class="col-md-6 recent rpts">
   <h2 class="report-title" itemprop="headline">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
   <?php  echo(types_render_field("first-name", array('raw' => true))); echo(" ");
      echo(types_render_field("last-name", array('raw' => true))); ?></a>
          </h2>
         <p><strong>Posted by:</strong> <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" class="url fn n"  rel="author" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="name"><?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?>
</span></a>  on <?php
$publish_date = '<time class="entry-date updated" datetime="' . get_the_time( 'c' ) . '" itemprop="datePublished">' . get_the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ) . '</time>';  echo $publish_date; ?><br />
    <strong>Dates Seen:</strong>  
<?php,$dates_seen = types_render_field("dates-seen", array('raw' => true)); echo($dates_seen); ?>
<br /> 
<strong>Affiliate:</strong>  
<?php echo(types_render_field("milb", array('raw' => true)));
<br />
   <strong>MLB Team</strong>
   <?php  echo(types_render_field("mlb-club", array('raw' => true))); ?>
     </p>
  </div>
<?php 
$pnum++;
endforeach; ?>
  </article>

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>       

      <?php 
            // Enable/Disable comments
            if ( $ti_option['site_page_comments'] == 1 ) {
                comments_template();
            } ?>

            <?php
            // Enable/Disable sidebar based on the field selection
            if ( ! get_field( 'page_sidebar' ) || get_field( 'page_sidebar' ) == 'page_sidebar_on' ): ?>

</div>
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div><!-- .grids -->
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</section><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the_field(), by definition, will echo out the value of the field onto the page and NOT store it inside a variable... instead you want to do this:

```
$showarticleposts =  get_field('articles-posts-to-show');
$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => $showarticleposts,
    'orderby'         => "post_date",
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'cat'             => '5, -58',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
```

To make sure it's getting what you want, do: `var_dump( $showarticleposts );` and see if a 2, as you claim it should be, is being dumped on the page.  Your third example "should" work, but you are using a different "field" name in each of your examples, so it's hard to tell if 'showarticleposts' or 'articles-posts-to-show' is the actual field name.

**UPDATE**

Since looking at your code... I have noticed that you are using `setup_postdata( $post );`.  While this is a great thing to use, it's changing your global `$post` variable, and therefore when you call `get_field()` it is using the `$post->ID` of the "changed" `$post` variable, which is not what you want.  You want the original `$post->ID` of the page you are currently viewing.  So, simply add `wp_reset_postdata();` after every custom loop you've created and it should fix the issue.

**UPDATE 2**
Since you mention it is STILL not working, the only other thing I can think of is to set a variable to the original page id at the **very top** of the page...

```
$current_page_id = get_the_ID();
```

Then when you call `get_field()`, include that id:

```
$showarticleposts = get_field( 'articles-posts-to-show', $current_page_id );
```

Comment: Thanks - I've actually tried this too - sorry for the confusing field names - I have several queries on the page, and I've tried different permutations in each. This also gives me the all posts result. It's very strange, because it seems like it really should work - but it doesn't. I thought maybe there was some trick to it. :)

Comment: Actually, when I added the var_sump code, I get this one the page "bool(false)" - which I'm thinking might be a problem.  But why would that be the result of var_dump( $showarticleposts );  if the field echoes "2"? Any idea?

Comment: You are getting "bool(false)" because the function will return false if it can't find the value you are looking for.  This is an indication of why things are failing.  You might need to pass the $post->ID to it, as per the documentation. `$field = get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value);`.  It would be helpful to see your entire page of code to see what's really going on.

Comment: Yes, I figured, but can't figure out why its echoes the code - except for maybe that is above the arrays? I'm adding the code above to my question.

Comment: Updated my answer... please review.

Comment: So - that didn't work either, although I suspect it should! I have ended up doing a ridiculously ugly bit of code, putting the entire $args = array( ....); code within a series of if else statements where $variable == "2" generate the array with numberpost => '2', and so on. Its absurd, there's no reason that should work where just populating the $variable with the field value doesn't.... Luckily (?) in this case, I only need 4 options for each - 2,4,6 or 8 posts. So while its ridiculous, it is functioning.

Comment: I updated the code again... give this option one last shot and then go for what you already did.  At least if my second update works, it'll be less ridiculous... :)

Comment: Although your exact solution didn't work for me, exactly, it got me there. The issue IS definitely something with the multiple queries. So instead I've just assigned all my variables above the start of the queries now - just after the_content, and before the various queries, and that works. So, I don't have to repeat the query 16 times with if statements. Thanks so much for helping me with this!